# Keyboard sticks randomly

Tags: 11.04, keyboard

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 10.04 to 11.04 and I encountered a strange problem with my keyboard.

While I am typing sometimes the last character I typed sticks, so it acts like I keep holding the the key down without releasing it.

For example if I typed "Ubuntu" the last "u" could stick and would be producing "Ubuntuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu" until I pressed any key on the keyboard. This happens randomly and I can't figure out under which circumstances this happens.
I have never experienced it on Ubuntu 10.04, so I doubt that this is something wrong with my hardware.

Comment: trust me - I'm not being funny - but obviously - you have turned your keyboard over and given it a good shake ? :)

Comment: Your English is all OK.

Comment: @fossfreedom It's definitely Ubuntu bug. You can google for it and see that other people had similar problem. When I boot Windows then everything works without any keyboard glitches. But when I use Ubuntu 11.04 keys may stick sporadically several times a day. Trust me my keyboard is fine ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since there are now [two related posts on this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59409/laptop-keyboard-has-gone-crazy) I'm guessing it's a bug. A simple workaround would be to turn off repeated key presses.

> 1. Click the icon at the very right of the top panel and select
>      System
>      Settings.
> 2. In the Hardware section, click Keyboard.
> 3. On the General tab, turn off Key presses repeat when key is held
>      down to disable
>      repeated keys entirely. Alternatively, adjust the Delay slider to
>      control how long you have to hold a key down to begin repeating
>      it,
>      and adjust the Speed slider to control how quickly key presses
>      repeat.

(via [Official Ubuntu Help Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/keyboard-repeat-keys.html).)

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work. I will mark your answer as accepted if I won't experience this keyboard glitches during following 2-3 days.

Comment: Your welcome. It should work. What's weird is, I can't think of a personal example as to why I would want this feature on by default. The only time I hold down a key press and expect it to be repeated is when I'm humorously emphasizing things with multiple exclamation points!!!!!!!!!!1 I never hold down a key to make it repeat for any legitimate reasons. Perhaps Ubuntu needs to rethink having this enabled by default.

Comment: While this might be a workaround, it doesn't address the fact that there's is some underlying bug -- most likely an IRQ problem -- that causes the key to stick. It's also an annoying work around, as then things as simple as holding down an error key to navigate text is broken.