# Laptop keyboard has gone crazy

Tags: keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard sticks randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58767/keyboard-sticks-randomly)

My laptop keyboard has gone crazy. When I type something on it, it's like I hammered the keys.
Example: hello myyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy name is gardar how are yoooooooooooooooooou?

This is more likely to happen when I type fast keyboard but also happens when I type real slowly.

Ubuntu 10.04 is my main OS along with OSE Virtualbox Win XP

This can't get anymore annoying and it's taking me about forever to post this message.

Comment: what do you mean, fossfreedom? I have turned internet upside down and not solution so far...

Comment: I've just linked you to a similar question - though no solution in that question yet.

Comment: I SEE< YES< THE PROBLEM IS SIMILAR

Answer (score 0):

Since there are now [two related posts on this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58767/keyboard-sticks-randomly) I'm guessing it's a bug.  A simple workaround would be to turn off repeated key presses.

> 1. Click the icon at the very right of the top panel and select
>      System
>      Settings.
> 2. In the Hardware section, click Keyboard.
> 3. On the General tab, turn off Key presses repeat when key is held
>      down to disable
>      repeated keys entirely. Alternatively, adjust the Delay slider to
>      control how long you have to hold a key down to begin repeating
>      it,
>      and adjust the Speed slider to control how quickly key presses
>      repeat.

(via [Official Ubuntu Help Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/keyboard-repeat-keys.html).)