# How do I report a bug related to the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, bug-reporting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

I am a novice Ubuntu user. I posted the below problem, but my question was closed and the moderator noted that it should have been reported as a bug. I followed the instructions for reporting the bug, but I don't know what package has the problem, so I needed to do a general bug reporting using `ubuntu-bug` in the "Run Application" window. Unfortunately, the only kinds of problems I can report are "security related", "sound/audio", "display", "external or internal storage", and "other". None seemed to fit my problem, so I chose "other" - but then got an error message that says "You need to specify a package or a PID."  Can someone please help me out here - and give me a clue as to what I did wrong? Thanks.

Question I originally posted:

> This is a slightly difficult problem to explain and it doesn't seem
>   like a hardware issue (though of course I am not sure). I have an Asus
>   EEE PC netbook running Ubuntu 10.10. The tilde key does not work (not
>   using shift and not as the single quote when not using shift). While
>   that is slightly annoying, it isn't such a big deal. What is a huge
>   problem is that randomly out of nowhere, I'll see a bunch of single
>   quotes being typed on the screen. It sometimes happens when I am in a
>   document, in an email, in a browser, or even typing in my password.
>   It's almost like there is some strange virus on my laptop that holds
>   down that button at random points in time. If I start clicking the
>   backspace button, it sometimes deletes them, but sometimes it feels
>   like the key is fighting back and just keeps typing the single quotes.
>   Sometimes (e.g, if I am in the box where I need to enter my password),
>   I can easily just hit ctrl-A and then delete, but sometime the problem
>   persists and I have trouble logging in.

Any thoughts on this? Thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Have you tried taking a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/58767/18612) to see if it helps with your keyboard issue?